# Infecting files on GitHub

Tags: malware, virus, github

Suppose one uploads (carelessly or purposefully) a file with a malicious payload to their Github account (some pdf document, picture, etc.). Could this payload somehow be executed on the Github servers (through preview or alike) and corrupt (infect) any other good files stored there (the years of important work one would like to keep)? And would it be safe to delete the suspicious file and move on with the rest of the data in the github account? A non-technical person might be tempted to wipe everything and start clean, but that would be overkill, right?

Comment: This would be the same as your email attachment question if your focus is solely on the Github server side. And like your other question, it's the syncing of the files locally that is the problem. Github doesn't "execute" the files one uploads.

Answer (score 0):

You seem **not** to understand how computers works in general, what operating systems are, what they do, and what the HTTP server is.

The simple act of uploading or downloading anything to or from the Internet does **not** entail any code execution. You're basically moving bytes from one storage to another one. These bytes are **not** automatically executed unless you instruct them to, e.g. by launching a downloaded exe or creating a script which processes them.